# Don't want to display INFO,WARN, DEBUG, etc messages on console

Tags: configuration, log4j

Below is my log4j.xml file. It's writing the logging information into a file, but i don't want to display the same logging information in the console.

Kindly suggest me a solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d 
         %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${myWebapp-instance-root}/WEB-INF/logs/application.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d 
            %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value="INFO"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: remove <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />

Comment: Ah, sorry, the diff viewer sucks. Restored to your revision.